# SQL Sort column 1 and add all values in column 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got a query that gets back a set of results that shows the shelf location and if the shelf is being used. The shelf layouts are like: "A1XXX01, A1XXX02" and then moving onto A2 and so on. The screenshot bellow shows the result set I am currently getting back, I want to sort the data in a way that it shows like this:

```
location   amountUsed   amountFree
   A1          200          100
   A2          100          500
   B1          520          100
```

This is the query I have so far and a screenshot of a small piece of data it gets back

```
SELECT 
wl.location,
CASE WHEN COALESCE(SUM(quantity), 0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as isUsed
FROM warehouse_locations as wl LEFT JOIN
     product_stock_warehouse as psw
     ON psw.location = wl.location 
WHERE wl.unitId_unitId LIKE '1'
GROUP BY wl.location 
order by wl.location
```

[image]

The "isUsed" column is 1 to show that the shelf is in use and 0 to show that it is free

Comment: Can you give us your table definition and a few examples of data ?

Comment: @kieronoates A11 is possible?

Comment: @JibinBalachandran It is formatted as "AXXXXX" as an incrementing number so yes it is possible but the A1 means its in warehouse A in location 1 and the rest of the string is incremented as 001A, 001B, 001C, 002A and so on

Comment: @kieronoates Is there a possibility of warehouse A in location 11? I mean A11XXXXX ??

Comment: @JibinBalachandran no, it goes to 9 and then moves onto alphabetical, there are a lot of records, my problem has been solved though thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone put an answer but shortly deleted it after and it worked, here is the working code after a few tweaks

```
SELECT  substring(location, 1, 2) as location,
    count(case when isUsed = 1 then location END) as amountUsed,
    count(case when isUsed = 0 then location END) as amountFree,
    count(isUsed) as totalShelves
FROM    (
            SELECT  wl.location,
                    CASE WHEN COALESCE(SUM(quantity), 0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as isUsed
            FROM    warehouse_locations as wl
            LEFT JOIN
                    product_stock_warehouse as psw
            ON      psw.location = wl.location 
            WHERE   wl.unitId_unitId LIKE '1'
            GROUP BY wl.location 
        ) t1
GROUP BY substring(location, 1, 2)
ORDER BY substring(location, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 
LEFT(wl.location,2) as shelf,
SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(SUM(quantity), 0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as isUsed,
SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(SUM(quantity), 0) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as isNotUsed

FROM warehouse_locations as wl LEFT JOIN
     product_stock_warehouse as psw
     ON psw.location = wl.location 
WHERE wl.unitId_unitId LIKE '1'
GROUP BY LEFT(wl.location,2)
order by LEFT(wl.location,2)
```

Assuming that shelves are always on a 2-character format.

P.S. You may have forgotten a wildcard on this part?

`wl.unitId_unitId LIKE '1'`
If you haven't, and it's really just like that.  you can just change that to `wl.unitId_unitId = '1'`

Answer (score 0):

So, looking at your question it appears you want to group your results by the first 2 characters of 'location'. Then you just need to tweak the case statements slightly. This is untested and there's probably a better way of doing it, but I think this should more or less work.

```
SELECT 
LEFT(wl.location, 2) as Location, --Gets first 2 characters
SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(SUM(quantity), 0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as TotalUsed, --Get a sum of total used
SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(SUM(quantity), 0) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TotalUnused, --Get a sum of total unused
FROM warehouse_locations as wl LEFT JOIN
 product_stock_warehouse as psw
 ON psw.location = wl.location 
WHERE wl.unitId_unitId LIKE '1'
GROUP BY SUBSTR(wl.location, 1, 2)
ORDER by Location
```